# How to proper manage redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm looking for the best practice approach for manage redux state in particular case:

I have an application for editing posts with content editor, application state looks like this:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      id: 123,
      blocks: [
        {
          setting1: 'fuzz',
          setting2: 'bar',
          ...
        }
      ],
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],

  activeBlock: {
    setting1: 'fuzz',
    setting2: 'bar',
    ...
  }
}
```

It's actually a state structure to which I want to come.

At this time I have the following structure:

```
{
  posts: [
    {
      id: 123,
      activeBlockIndex: 0,
      blocks: [
        {
          setting1: 'fuzz',
          setting2: 'bar',
          ...
        }
      ],
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

And I have one common reducer for posts and content blocks. And It's important to mention that `Content Editor` component very complex and has so many goes deep down child components. It's seems to be ok and it works.. *But* I have a problem: I have to specify so much information about posts, in the `Content Editor`'s components e.g.: postId, blockIndex. I think it's not so good, because main responsibility of the `Content Editor` component it's just -- editing the content, no matter where it's stored.

I want to refactor my app so `Content Editor`'s components will contain reference only for the `state.activeBlock` and other components for managing posts and blocks only for `state.posts`. (first variant of the structure in the question)

In other words I'm looking for a way for sync `state.activeBlock` branch of state to `state.posts` at the reducers level (or somewhere else, I don't know).

I really appreciate any advices.

Btw, is it clear what I'm talking about? Or question should be rewritten in more detailed way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding exactly what you're asking, but if you want multiple "areas" of state per your example, you can use `combineReducers`. Eg `store.js`

```
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

import postsReducer from './reducers/postsReducer'
import activeBlockReducer from './reducers/activeBlockReducer'

const reducers = {
    posts: postsReducer,
    activeBlock: activeBlockReducer
}

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers)
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware
    )
)

export default store
```

In `mapStateToProps` you can use `state.posts[0]` and `state.activeBlock.setting1` to connect to your components.

Comment: Yes, I already use combineReducers. Thanks for mention about mapStateToProps, I forgot that I have access to whole store object inside mapStateToProps function. But I'm not sure Is this ok for doing sync stuff right here?

Comment: `mapStateToProps` is only to connect state to components, and not for setting state at all. If you don't want to _move_ setting1, setting2 etc into `activeBlock`, then there's no reason to have duplicate state. You could set `active: true` on the active post in `state.posts` from your Reducer, then in `mapStateToProps` of the ContentEditor component, `let activePost = state.posts.filter(post => post.active)[0]; return { post: activePost }`. That will set the `post` prop in ContentEditor to the active post, and give you its settings.

Comment: Alternatively (and more likely) you will have the `id` of the post that the user is editing in the URL, and you could filter `posts` by ID...